# How to properly change Canonicalization Method in this Java code?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, digital-signature, canonicalization

I'm using

```
import org.apache.xml.security.c14n.Canonicalizer;
```

in my code, and the line used to Canonicalize the signature looks like this:

```
outputStream.write(Canonicalizer.getInstance(Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N_WITH_COMMENTS).canonicalizeSubtree(doc));
```

My problem is that this method leaves me with an XML file canonicalized using Method `http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315` while `http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#` is what I'm being asked to do.

So, as someone absolutely new to the world of digital signatures and the like: is there a quick and easy fix I could do to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a canonicalization method that excludes XML comments, in this case [`ALGO_ID_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS`](https://santuario.apache.org/Java/api/org/apache/xml/security/c14n/Canonicalizer.html#ALGO_ID_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS), which translates to `http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#`.

More details on the Apache Santuario library's [constant field values overview](https://santuario.apache.org/Java/api/index.html).

Comment: While this seems to make sense, I changed the line in the code (when I hover over it, even Eclipse says that Canonicalization Method is now ```http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#```), but the XML output file looks identical to the one generated with the unchanged code, and it still says that it's using ```http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315``` Method. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No idea. Double check that you compiled your changes and that you're looking at the right XML file.

Comment: While the problem described above persisted, I found out I am not the only person having it, but no solution is to be found yet. Since I dedicated another post to it, I will be marking this answer as the correct one since it should have solved the problem by all means, while something else seems to be causing it.